# Some questions about convert caffe model to torch

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, torch

I use [torch-caffe-binding](https://github.com/szagoruyko/torch-caffe-binding) to convert caffe model to torch. And I want to delete the loss layer in the end and add other torch layers, could I just delete the layer in the `.prototxt` file and "train" the model to get the `.caffemodel` file and import in torch?
And the model uses the lmdb type data, when I use `net:forward(input)` to train the model, the model just uses the data defined in the data layer instead of uses the `input`data. So how to train the model that uses the lmdb data?
the caffe model has some custom layer so I can't use the `loadcaffe` to load the model in torch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 issues here -

1. You probably need the loss layer for the training (this is what you
   want to minimize). So train with it, and after the training is done
   remove it from your prototxt before converting to torch.
2. In order to use the lmdb rather than using the data layer, connect
   your input to the first conv layer (assuming your first non-input
   layer is conv, e.g. say you have

   ```
   layer {
     name: "input-data"
     type: "DummyData"
     top: "data"
     top: "im_info"
     dummy_data_param {
       shape { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 224 dim: 224 }
     }
   }
   ```

   and also

   ```
   input: "data"
   input_shape: {
   dim: 1
   dim: 3
   dim: 224
   dim: 224
   }
   ```

   and then

   ```
   layer {
     name: "conv1"
     type: "Convolution"
     bottom: "data" --> **here put data instead of input-data**
     top: "conv1"
     convolution_param {
       num_output: 96
       kernel_size: 3
       pad: 1
       stride: 1
     }
   }
   ```
3. As for the custom layer, you'll have to find an equivalent
   implementation in torch or implement it on your own

Comment: when i remove the loss layer in the prototxt, the console shows like this:`I0923 20:56:19.437440 23288 net.cpp:200] conv1 does not need backward computation.`all the layers have the save message.and i can't use torch to train it.When i add the loss layer,everything goes right,how can i remove the loss layer while all layers need backward?Thanks in advance.

Comment: i found how to solve it,just add `loss_weight: 1`in the last layer.thanks for your help

Comment: when i use `net = caffe.Net('test.prototxt','test.caffemodel','train')` and `net:getParameters()` to get the `netGradParameters`.but i get `[torch.DoubleTensor with no dimension]`,and i can't train it in torch.So if the caffe model can't train in torch or i use the wrong way to train it?